# HTML validator error "Attribute src not allowed on element a"

Tags: html, facebook, w3c-validation

While running HTML validator on my HTML code, the following error is encountered:

> Error: Attribute src not allowed on element a at this point.

The code snippet where the error occurs is:

```html
<a    class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" 
      target="_blank" 
       href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://testingsite.com/j8h' 
       src="sdkTesting"
       title="Facebook">
```

How can I fix? Some internet pages tells me go with `data-src` rather than `src` attribute, while there is no information on Facebook regarding this.

Comment: so what's wrong simple use `<a    class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" 
      target="_blank" href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://testingsite.com/j8h'  data-src="sdkTesting" title="Facebook">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply Use **`data-`** with all attr for example

```
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"
target="_blank"
data-href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://testingsite.com/j8h'
data-src="sdkTesting"
title="Facebook"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` tag in HTML does not take in an attribute of `src`. The `href` attribute should work just fine in your code. Your code should look like:

```
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://testingsite.com/j8h' title="Facebook"></a>
```

But if you say the reason why you need a `src` attribute in your code maybe there's a workaround otherwise just use JavaScript for any kind of DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

`src` can't be used with `<a>` tag. To see the list for its support, [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_src.asp).